# how to combine "prefix" with "range"?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to search using `prefix` and `range`.

This works:

```
GET /traffic-*/_search
{
  "query": {
      "prefix": {
          "src": {
              "value": "192."
          }
      }
  }
}
```

But when I try to throw in `range` I get an error:

```
GET /traffic-*/_search
{
 "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "src": {
          "value": "192."
      }
    },
    "bool": {
        "must": [
              {
                "range" : {
                    "score" : {
                        "gte": 7
                    }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
    }
 }
```

Here's the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[prefix] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line": 8,
        "col": 5
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[prefix] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
    "line": 8,
    "col": 5
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I tried it a lot of other ways, including like this, but still got the same error:

```
GET /traffic-*/_search
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "prefix": {
              "src": {
                  "value": "192."
                }
              },
              "range" : {
                  "score" : {
                      "gte": 7
                  }
              }
            }]
          }
    }
 }
```

How do I correct this syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add "prefix" and "range" query inside Must Bool Query.
Like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "src": {
              "value": "192."
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "score": {
              "gte": 7
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```